# Github creates new branch like it was created at the time of my last pull request?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project, and i have had this issue for a while. Lets say that i last made a pull request 2 days ago. When i create a new branch, it will say that it was created 2 days ago, at the time of that pull request, so i can't see the updates the other project members have made. I have tried deleting the braches and waiting, but it does not seem to work.

Do any of you with more experience using Github know what the issue might be, and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: How are you creating the new branch? In the Github UI? Using git on the command-line? Using a GUI?

Comment: I am using GitHub desktop, so by tapping current branch, and the selecting new branch

Comment: @user17157762: that makes this a question about the GitHub-Desktop GUI, not about Git, nor about GitHub. Note, however, that when using Git—which all of these systems do—there are multiple complete copies of repositories, and each copy has *its own* (private-to-it) branch names. One Git repository can *see* some other Git repository's branch names, but cannot actually *use* them directly.

Comment: As a general rule, one Git repository will connect to another with `git fetch` or `git push`. *At that time* it sees the other repository's branch names. It can then update its own *memory* of that other repository's branch names, but that's all it can do directly. If you are using `git push`, the push protocol ends with an exchange where the sender can *ask* the receiver: *Please set some of your branch names to particular commit hash IDs*. The receiver can comply with the request or reject it.

Comment: What all this means is that except when you run `git fetch` or `git push` (note that `git pull` means *run `git fetch` to get commits, then run a second Git command to use the commits we just got*), all the things you do in your local Git repository are *strictly local*. They won't affect the copy of the repository over on GitHub at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Git is a **de-centralized** version control system: every "working copy" is actually a completely independent version repository, and git provides commands for transferring data between them.

This is easiest to see if you disconnect from the internet, and carry on working locally - you'll still be able to create branches, commit to them, merge them, and so on. Even once you connect to the internet again, there is no automatic job that will re-synchronise anything, **you have to tell git what data to fetch or share**.

That's what the "git fetch", "git pull", and "git push" commands are for:

- to get an updated view of what's on a remote repository, you run "git fetch"
- to bring changes into a local branch which exist on a remote repository, you run "git pull", which is basically the same as "git fetch" followed by "git merge"
- to share changes on a local branch *to* a remote repository, you run "git push"

So, your branches are missing other people's changes, because you based them on an out of date snapshot of the shared development branch.